# How to determine whether a hexadecimal number is a negative one?

Tags: hex

How can you say that 0x80000000 is negative? Also for knowing whether its negative or not, do I need to convert it in to binary first? Please enlighten me on this.

Comment: _“How can you say that 0x80000000 is negative?”_ – you can’t; not without specifying what number system you are using beforehand.

Comment: What? Doesn't the 0x here represent that it is a hexadecimal number? @CBroe

Comment: Yes, but that’s not what I meant. As in the other answer, _“assuming you're talking about 32-bit signed integers”_ …

Answer (score 1):

`0x80000000` is equivalent to `0b10000000000000000000000000000000`.

I'm assuming you're talking about 32-bit signed integers. If so, they are stored in a two's-complement format. Basically, this means that the first bit indicates the sign (`0` for positive, `1` for negative), and the remaining digits indicate the actual number. If the sign was negative, the remaining bits are flipped and one is subtracted (because there's no negative zero). Therefore, this number (in 32-bit signed form) is `-0b1111111111111111111111111111111`, or `-2147483648`.

Comment: +1, though not quite right on the two's-complement.  0x80000000 is -2147483648.

Comment: Hi, you said that it is stored in 2's complemetn format, but you haven't yet changed 80000000 in to that? but just by seeing the msd u said its negative? @Doorknob of Snow

Comment: Oops! okay, forgot that 2's complement is the same! Thank you @DoorknobofSnow